# Reaper Post Production

Tags: reaper, post-production, daw, film-sound-design

Do you guys know how to snap fades on one region in relation to another region on a seperate track, aligning the two for a precise cross fade? Snapping length of regions compared to other tracks, though a little fimicky, works fine, but quick accurate fade snapping isn't working for me. I enjoyed this function on ProTools and Sony's Acid. I haven't found a solution pop up on the Cockos forum yet.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really in on Reaper, but I've noticed that Macprovideo.com has been putting out a bunch of series on that and they're pretty cheap. I don't think it's mac specific, they've just combined with askvideo.com for stuff. Wish I could help with the actual issue, but if you're a Reaper user, figured you'd want to know.

Answer (score 1):

REAPER user here. As far as I know REAPER doesn't have this function, unfortunately. Create a request on the forum and they might create it for you though! I know I'd use it too!